# Passing text from a function to a gui

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I've got a GUI function in a file 'test_gui.py', which is adapted from one of Bryan Oakley's answers to a question regarding getting text from a Tkinter entry box.

```
  import sys
  import os
  import Tkinter as tk

  class testing(tk.Tk):
      def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Enter benchmark version")
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Enter test_suite (a for all)")
        self.label3 = tk.Label(self, text = "Enter sub_suite t or w")
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        self.label1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.label2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.label3.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.entry2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.entry3.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

     def on_button(self):

        benchmark = self.entry1.get()
        test_suite = self.entry2.get()
        sub_suite = self.entry3.get()
        home_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        path = os.path.join(home_path, sub_suite, 'results')
        sys.path.insert(0, path)
        import compare_data as compare
        compare.compare_results(benchmark, test_suite)
        self.label4 = tk.Label(self, text=fil)
        self.button2.grid(row = 5, column = 10)
app = testing()
app.mainloop()
```

and I need to pass it 'fil' from a different function which is run after pressing button through the function compare_results. In this function I've got:

```
 import test_gui

 test_gui.testing(fil)
```

To do this I think I need to define on_button as

```
  def on_button(self, fil)
```

But then this returns the error that on_button requires two arguments. If I give fil a default value it will pass that to the label on pressing the button.

Is there a way of passing text from a function run through a gui back to the gui?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda to pass more arguments to the button command.
So instead of

```
command = self.on_button
```

You could use

```
command = lambda: self.on_button(fil)
```

To pass 'fil' to the on_button function.
Is this what you had in mind?